# phoenix undefined function changeset/3

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I study the framework phoenix.
Is a model of the image that will be stored in the cloud storage. When creating an image I calculate the hash of the file, and take it as a :name. I made a model, controller and view. But I do not understand why I receive an error:

```
== Compilation error on file web/models/image.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/models/image.ex:26: undefined function changeset/3
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:116: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

I have reviewed all of your code, but did not find the place where I call Image.changeset with three parameters. 
My image.ex:

```
defmodule Blog.Image do
  use Blog.Web, :model

  schema "images" do
    field :name, :string
    field :original_name, :string
    field :filename, :string, virtual: true

    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w(
    name
    original_name
    filename
  )
  @optional_fields ~w()

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end

  def create_changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> changeset(struct, params)
    |> generate_name_hash
  end

  defp generate_name_hash(changeset) do
    put_change(changeset, :name, gen_hash_name(changeset[:filename]))
  end

  defp gen_hash_name(filename) do
    hash_name = :crypto.hash(:sha256, File.read(filename))
    |> Base.encode16
    "/"<>slice(hash_name, 0, 2)<>"/"<>slice(hash_name, 2, 2)<>"/"<>slice(hash_name, 4, 2)
  end

end
```

my image_controller.ex:

```
defmodule Blog.ImageController do
  use Blog.Web, :controller
  plug Addict.Plugs.Authenticated when action in [:new, :create]

  def new(conn, _params) do
    changeset = Blog.Image.changeset(%Blog.Image{})
    render conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset
  end

  def create(conn, %{"image" => image_params}) do
    full_image_params = %{filename: image_params["image"].path, original_name: image_params["image"].filename}
    changeset = Blog.Image.create_changeset(%Blog.Image{}, full_image_params)
    case Blog.Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, image} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Image created successfully.")
        |> redirect(to: image_path(conn, :show, image))
      {:error, changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
end
```

my new.html.eex:

```
<%= form_for @changeset, image_path(@conn, :create), [role: "form", multipart: true], fn f -> %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label f, :image, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= file_input f, :image, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= error_tag f, :image %>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-default" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this:

```
 def create_changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> changeset(struct, params)
    |> generate_name_hash
  end
```

Should be

```
 def create_changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> changeset(params)
    |> generate_name_hash
  end
```

Because `|>` operator passes whatever is to the left of it as the first argument to the function to the right. So you're basically doing `changeset(struct, struct, params)`

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace tells you exactly where your error is: 
    `** (CompileError) web/models/image.ex:26: undefined function changeset/3`.

I believe you're trying to use the `cast` function since a `changeset` function does not exist natively in [Ecto changesets](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast/3). Also, `cast` has an arity of three so you're missing an argument.

Change this on line 26:

```
def create_changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  |> changeset(struct, params)
  |> generate_name_hash
end
```

to this:

```
def create_changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  |> cast(params, [:name, :original_name, :filename])   #<---- 3rd arg. = 'allowed'
  |> generate_name_hash
end
```

Where `cast` function requires three arguments `cast(data, params, allowed)`. All parameters that are not explicitly allowed are ignored.

And like Mchl said, the result of functions are passed to the FIRST argument to the next function in pipe operations (in this specific post you don't need to pass `struct` explicitly).